# Running python script with gurobipy module from qt

Tags: python, qt, gurobi

I want to run a python script from Qt, when the user clicks a button. This script works properly in a terminal but I get an error when I execute from Qt.

I have tried to execute the script from Pycharm IDE and I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ana/PycharmProjects/Gurobi/one_set.py", line 1, in <module>
   from gurobipy import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .gurobipy import *
ImportError: libgurobi81.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I execute "import gurobipy" in a python console, I get no error.

> > > import gurobipy
> > >
> > > import pkg_resources
> > >
> > > pkg_resources.get_distribution("gurobipy").version

'8.1.1'

Searching libgurobi81.so, I check that this file exists in:

```
/opt/gurobi811/linux64/lib/libgurobi81.so

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobi811/linux64/lib/libgurobi81.so

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy/libgurobi81.so
```

As suggested in install instructions, I have included environment variables in /home/usr/.bashrc as:

```
export GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi811/linux64"

export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
```

I also included the other directories that contain libgurobi81.so:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobi811/

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy/
```

However, from terminal everything works fine and I get the solution:

/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ana/PycharmProjects/Gurobi/one_set.py

Academic license - for non-commercial use only

```
 instance     objVal          time

Instance1.csv    0.030176      0.0002670288

 [1 rows x 2 columns]
```

The code I use to run python script from Qt is:

```
   QString  command("/usr/bin/python2.7");
   QStringList params = QStringList() << "/home/ana/PycharmProjects/Gurobi/one_set.py";

   QProcess *process = new QProcess();
   process->startDetached(command, params);
   process->waitForFinished();
   qDebug()<<process->readAllStandardOutput();
   process->close();
```

I expected the same output from Qt as from terminal, since the command I use to run it is the same:
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ana/PycharmProjects/Gurobi/one_set.py

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The solution was adding environment variables before the start of the process:

```
   QString  command("/usr/bin/python2.7");
   QStringList params = QStringList();
   params.append("/home/ana/PycharmProjects/Gurobi/one_set.py");


   QProcess *process = new QProcess();
   QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
   env.insert("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/usr/local/lib:/opt/gurobi811/linux64/lib:/opt/gurobi811/linux64/lib:/opt/gurobi811/linux64/lib/"); // Add an environment variable
   process->setProcessEnvironment(env);


   process->start(command, params);
   process->waitForFinished();
   QString p_stdout = process->readAllStandardOutput();
   ui->Output->setText(p_stdout);
   process->close();
```